# «Срок годности: 2 года». Каким членом предложения является «2 года»?

Tags: синтаксис, члены-предложения, двоеточие

Повсеместно встречается следующая постановка знаков препинания:

> Срок годности: 2 года.

Каким членом предложения в таком случае является **«2 года»**?

В случае тире это двусоставное предложение. В случае двоеточия это два назывных предложения или назывное предложение с пояснительным членом предложения? Или же это предложение тоже следует рассматривать как двусоставное?
Как рассматривать подобные конструкции: «Телефон: 89852341933», «Адрес: г. Москва, ул. Тверская», «Имя: Сергей», «Хобби: рыбалка»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Срок годности — 2 года.**

Тире между подлежащим и составным именным сказуемым

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

4. Тире ставится, если оба главных члена предложения выражены количественными числительными или если один из них выражен формой именительного падежа существительного, а другой — числительным либо оборотом с числительным: Двадцать лет — хорошая вещь (Сим.);  Скорость — шестьдесят километров в час.

Примечание. В специальной литературе при характеристике предмета тире в этом случае часто не ставится: Грузоподъёмность крана 2,5 тонны, вылет стрелы 5 метров; Температура плавления золота 1063о С.

**Вопрос № 211672**
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой знак препинания - тире или двоеточие - ставится в следующих случаях: Гарантия 2 года. Срок службы 20.000 часов.
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
**По правилу ставится тире**.

2) **«Адрес: г. Москва, ул. Тверская», «Имя: Сергей», «Хобби: рыбалка».**

В таких конструкциях ставится двоеточие, они ближе к теме, связанной с перечнями, где тире не ставится. В этом случае во второй части раскрывается содержание первой.

Это особые конструкции, предложениями их не называют, но по структуре **они близки к предложениям с пояснительным членом** : Мой адрес такой/следующий...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79410/discussion-on-answer-by-jasmin---2----).

Comment: Пояснительный член предложения (инфинитив, как в примере выше) является тем же членом предложения, содержание которого он поясняет?

Answer (score 1):

"Нормальная", литературная форма — с тире. **Срок годности — 2 года.** Тире стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Форма с двоеточием характерна для анкет и им подобных бюрократических документов, в которых заполняются определенные графы (ячейки информации), в том числе для компьютерных форм ввода данных. На этикетках тоже пишут через двоеточие. Думаю, нужно рассматривать такие построения как БСП, состоящие из двух назывных  предложений.

> [Вопрос № 260836](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=260836)
>   Здравствуйте!
>   Подскажите, пожалуйста, в предложениях типа: "Ваш самый удачный совет", "Ваше первое признание в любви" нужно ли ставить вопросительный знак? 
>   Спасибо! Удачного дня!
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка** 
>   Если это вопросы (задаются с вопросительной интонации), то знак ставится. Но **в пункте анкеты правильнее будет поставить двоеточие** (далее - ответ).
>
> [Вопрос № 281037](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=281037%20)
>    Здравствуйте.
>   Помогите, пожалуйста, в грамотном составлении информации на продуктовой этикетке.
>   Прежде всего интересует пунктуация в случаях, не предусматривающих перечисления: "Производитель...", "Дата изготовления..." (в случае "Произведено..." очевидно, что вообще в з/п нет необходимости), "Масса нетто...". Повсеместно употребляется двоеточие, но лично у меня оно вызывает сомнения. По мне, так уместнее тире.
>   Знаки градусов и процентов пишутся без пробелов, в отличие от сокращений "г.", "гр.", верно? )
>   Какой предлог употребляется в конструкции "Срок годности[?] 12 месяцев [с/со/от] [даты/дня] производства."
>   Естественно, все эти однострочечные предложения надо закрывать точкой, да? )
>   Благодарю!
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Допустимо тире, двоеточие и отсутствие знака: Дата изготовления: 20.02.2015 или Дата изготовления – 20.02.2015 или Дата изготовления 20.02.2015. Употребительность двоеточия можно объяснить тем, что этот знак предупреждает читателя: внимание, дальше будет важная информация.
>   Последняя цифра числа отбивается от обозначения °С, правильно: 10 °С. Но: 10° (без обозначения шкалы). Знак % отбивают от цифр: 10 %.
>   Допустимо: со дня производства и с даты производства.

Comment: Можно ли рассматривать «2 года» как сказуемое?

Comment: Не уверен. Вам лучше подождать ответов других участников.